# Many to many to another many to many on single entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have fairly simple question about many to many relationships using entity framework.

Situation looks like this I have 3 models SectionName:

```
public class SectionName : BaseEntity
{
    public SectionName()
    {
        SectionsSuffix = new List<SectionSuffix>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SectionSuffix> SectionsSuffix { get; set; }
}
```

Section Suffix:

```
[Table("SectionsSuffix")]
public class SectionSuffix : BaseEntity
{
    public SectionSuffix()
    {
        SectionLines = new List<SectionLine>();
        SectionsName = new List<SectionName>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SectionLine> SectionLines { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SectionName> SectionsName { get; set; }
}
```

And SectionLines:

```
[Table("SectionLines")]
public class SectionLine : BaseEntity
{
    public SectionLine()
    {
        SectionsSuffix = new List<SectionSuffix>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SectionSuffix> SectionsSuffix { get; set; }
}
```

Now SectionsName is related by many to many to SectionsSuffix and that is related with many to many to SectionLines, in context using FluentApi and junction tables:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SectionName>()
            .HasMany(suffix => suffix.SectionsSuffix)
            .WithMany(name => name.SectionsName)
            .Map(nameSuffix =>
            {
                nameSuffix.ToTable("SectionsNameSuffix");
                nameSuffix.MapLeftKey("SectionNameId");
                nameSuffix.MapRightKey("SectionSuffixId");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SectionSuffix>()
            .HasMany(line => line.SectionLines)
            .WithMany(suffix => suffix.SectionsSuffix)
            .Map(nameSuffix =>
            {
                nameSuffix.ToTable("SectionsSuffixLines");
                nameSuffix.MapLeftKey("SectionSuffixId");
                nameSuffix.MapRightKey("SectionLinesId");
            });
    }
```

Now, if with no problem when I call SectionsNames I can get SectionsSuffix list, I want to with this one call get also list of SectionNames binged to specific SectionSuffix, is it possible?

For now using repository pattern procedure looks like this:

```
    IList<SectionName> sections = SectionRepository.GetAll(x => x.SectionsSuffix).ToList();

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable query = includes.Aggregate(_dbSet.AsQueryable(), (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        return (IEnumerable<T>) query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was fairly simple, i would need to use:

```
IList<SectionName> sections = SectionRepository.GetAll(name => name.SectionsSuffix, 
name => name.SectionsSuffix.Select(suffix => suffix.SectionLines)).ToList();

public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable query = includes.Aggregate(_dbSet.AsQueryable(), (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    return (IEnumerable<T>) query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I would query sth. like you want to do, it would be like that:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

public class SectionRepository
{
    private readonly _context;


    public SectionRepository(IMyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context
    }

    public ICollection<SectionName> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.SectionNames
            .Include(sn => sn.SectionsSuffix.SectionLine)
            .Select(sn => sn).ToList();
    }
}
```

Please have a try, the code above is not tested.